# How to simulate click on child element using enzyme and sinon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sinon, enzyme

I am using using enzyme and sinon, I receive this error when trying to use this test case:

> Expected value to equal:
>         true
>       Received:
>         false

In console when using `.debug()` I see:

Apparently event handler for click is not being called.

I suspect the issue could be related to `.simulate('click', onLocationClick)`.

Could you please help me out and tell what I am doing wrong here? Thanks.

```
 console.log src\forecast\locationFinder\LocationFinder.test.js:28
      <Location country="CZ" id={3067696} name="Prague" onLocationClick={[Function]} />
```

```js
  it('should click event', () => {
    const data = [
      {
        country: 'CZ',
        id: 3067696,
        name: 'Prague'
      },
      {
        country: 'US',
        id: 4548393,
        name: 'Prague'
      }
    ]
    const onLocationClick = sinon.spy()
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <LocationFinder
        locations={data}
        onLocationClick={onLocationClick}
    />)
    console.log(wrapper.find({ id: 3067696 }).debug())
    wrapper.find({ id: 3067696 }).simulate('click', onLocationClick)
    expect(onLocationClick.called).toEqual(true)
  })
```

Answer (score 5):

From the official Enzyme [docs](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html):

> - Currently, event simulation for the shallow renderer does not
>     propagate as one would normally expect in a real environment. As a
>     result, one must **call `.simulate()` on the actual node** that has the
>     event handler set.
> - Even though the name would imply this simulates an actual event,
>     **`.simulate()` will in fact target the component's prop** based on the
>     event you give it. For example, `.simulate('click')` will actually get
>     the `onClick` prop and call it.

Keeping the above two points in mind, you can try the following:

**1. Registered Events**

Check if `onLocationClick` is registered with the `click` event. Does it have another event name like `locationclick`? Likely, it is not registered as an event at all, just a prop function.

**2. Underlying Components**

Does `<Location />` encapsulate another component or element with `onClick()` handler defined? If yes, dive down and `.find()` that element via the `wrapper` and simulate `click` on it. e.g.

```
wrapper.find({ id: 3067696 }).dive().find('li > a').simulate('click');
expect(onLocationClick.called).toEqual(true);
```

Like @GibboK has done, you can also store the underlying element as a constant, and check if it exists, before simulating click.

Comment: In my case <LocationFinder /> encapsulate <Location /> which at the end is composed of <li>
    <a onClick={onLocationClick}>{name}, {country}</a>
  </li>

Comment: Problem I have I cannot get find the html element within <Location />, could you please help me out. I would be glad to accept you answer, thanks

Comment: I like this answer +1 but I would suggest using .dive()

Comment: @Radex What error do you get when you dive then find the underlying component?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using enzyme `.dive()` More [info](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html) here. Which:

> Shallow render the one non-DOM child of the current wrapper, and
>   return a wrapper around the result.

Your code should looks like:

```js
  it('should click event', () => {
    const data = [
      {
        country: 'CZ',
        id: 3067696,
        name: 'Prague'
      },
      {
        country: 'US',
        id: 4548393,
        name: 'Prague'
      }
    ]
    const onLocationClick = sinon.spy()
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <LocationFinder
        locations={data}
        onLocationClick={onLocationClick}
    />)
    const dom = wrapper.find({ id: 3067696 }).dive().find('li > a')
    expect(dom.length).toBe(1)

    dom.simulate('click')
    expect(onLocationClick.called).toEqual(true)
  })
```